# Convergence of $\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{S_n}{T_n}-\frac{\mu_X}{\mu_Y} \right)$ where $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $T_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nY_i$

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers, bivariate-distributions

Suppose $(X_i, Y_i),i\geq 1$ are i.i.d. bivariate r.v. wit $E(X_1)=\mu_x$, $E(Y_1)=\mu_y$ and $Var(X_1)=\sigma^2_x$, $Var(Y_1)=\sigma^2_y$ and $Corr(X_1,Y_1)=\rho_{xy}$. If $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are positive r.v.s, show that $$
Z_n=\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i}-\frac{\mu_x}{\mu_y} \right)
$$ 
converges in distribution to normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance 
$$
\frac{1}{\mu^4_y}(\mu^2_y\sigma^2_x+\mu^2_x\sigma^2_y-2\rho_{xy}\mu_x\mu_y\sigma_x\sigma_y)
$$
One of my friend solved it by approximating the denominator, but if anyone can give a simple solution, that would be great. Right now I am trying to find a *rather easy to calculate* solution, any hint or trick would be appreciable. **No need to give the full solution.**

Comment: Note that $$Z_n=\frac{U_n}{\mu_XV_n}$$ where $$U_n=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}W_i\qquad W_i=\mu_YX_i-\mu_XY_i\qquad V_n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$$ What can you say about $U_n$ when $n\to\infty$? What can you say about $V_n$ when $n\to\infty$? Thus...

Comment: @Did Using CLT, $U_n\Rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$, where $$\sigma^2=\mu^2_y\sigma^2_x+\mu^2_x\sigma^2_y-2\rho_{xy}\mu_x\mu_y\sigma_x\sigma_y
$$ and $V_n\rightarrow_p \mu_y$, then $$Z_n\Rightarrow N(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^2_x \mu^2_y})$$ But denominator is not same in variance part.

Comment: @Did Again how to prove $Z_n=X_n/Y_n$, $X_n\Rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$, $Y_n\rightarrow_p a$, then $Z_n\Rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2 /a^2)$?

Comment: @MANMAID Slutsky's theorem.

Comment: Oh, thsnks @NCh , what about variance part?

Comment: @MANMAID If $Var(X)=\sigma^2$ then $Var(X/a)=?$

Comment: @NCh I was saying that the variance came my case is $\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^2_x \mu^2_y}$, but in the problem it was given $\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^4_y}$.

Comment: @MANMAID Did you check whether $Z_n=\frac{U_n}{\mu_XV_n}$? I see that $Z_n=\frac{U_n}{\mu_YV_n}$.

Comment: @NCh Oh! my bad, thanks a lot, it's done now!

Comment: @MANMAID Post an answer then?

Comment: @Did it's done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution of the problem using the help of Did and NCh:**

$$Z_n=\frac{U_n}{\mu_y V_n}$$
$$U_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}W_i,\space W_i=\mu_yX_i-\mu_xY_i, \space \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$$
Using CLT, we have $U_n\Rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$, where $\sigma^2=\mu^2_y\sigma^2_x+\mu^2_x\sigma^2_y-2\rho_{xy}\mu_x\mu_y\sigma_x\sigma_y$

$V_n\rightarrow_p \mu_y$. Note that since $Y_1>0$ a.e., we have $\mu_y>0$.

Using Slutsky's theorem, we have the final result,
$$Z_n\Rightarrow N\Big{(}0,\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^4_y}\Big)$$ which is our desired result.